# Installing rudolf2 in Ubuntu

Tags: pip

I'm trying to install `rudolf2` using pip in Ubuntu by using the command:

```
pip install --user rudolf2==0.3
```

I need version 0.3..

I'm getting the following error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rudolf2==0.3
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for rudolf2==0.3

How can I fix?

Answer (score 1):

packet could be installed manually:

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/88/c5/1f96b6cf063de20493607a7e401572c819c399249c1fb5ce90bef4d3dbaa/rudolf-0.3.tar.gz#md5=dac4f105bfe40dbd70404af0d8c912f4
tar xvf rudolf2-0.3.tar.gz
cd rudolf2-0.3
python setup.py install
```

additionally you may need packet "nose"

```
pip install nose==1.3.7
```